# Getting Specific Value from Dmidecode Output with Bash Script

Tags: bash

Below is a section from the dmidecode output. There is a part of this section that I want to break down. I want to get the 4 bytes after pattern **01 85 30**. And I want to change the byte order. Then I will compare with the hex strings I have.

```bash
....... 
Handle 0x0027, DMI type 219, 106 bytes
OEM-specific Type
        Header and Data:
                DB 6A 27 00 01 04 01 45 02 00 90 06 *01 85 30* 20
                00 00 00 00 40 00 00 03 1F 24 02 C9 02 60 44 02
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 03 00 00 00 80 00 00 00
                00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
                00 04 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
                FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF
.......
```

I prepared a bash script and it works, is there a better way?

```bash
#!/bin/bash

id_array=("00000020", "00000040")
unique_id=$(dmidecode -t 219 | grep "01 85 30" -A 1 | xargs | cut -c 46-56 | tr -d '[:space:]' | grep -o .. | tac | paste -sd ''  -)
if [[ " ${id_array[*]} " == *"$unique_id"* ]];
then
  echo "1"
else
  echo "0"
fi
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script should work, but there is room for improvement. Instead of using `grep` and `cut`, you can use `awk` to extract the bytes after the pattern 01 85 30 and reverse their order. Here's an example:

```
unique_id=$(dmidecode -t 219 | awk '/01 85 30/ {getline; gsub(/ /,""); print substr($0,9,8)}' | tac -rs ..)
```

This awk command searches for the pattern 01 85 30, reads the next line, removes all spaces, and prints the 4 bytes starting from the 9th position (which is after the 8-byte timestamp). The result is then piped to `tac -rs ..` to reverse the byte order.

In addition, you can simplify the array search by using parameter expansion instead of grep:

```
if [[ ${id_array[*]} =~ $unique_id ]]; then
  echo "1"
else
  echo "0"
fi
```

This tests whether the expanded array `${id_array[*]}` contains the string `$unique_id`. The `=~` operator is used for pattern matching.

Comment: Thanks your finger but not worked, after the pattern 01 85 30. There is a 20. But you eliminated it.

Comment: @embedded4ever maybe add ` | tail -n1 | tac -rs ..` instead of just ` | tac -rs ..` ?

Comment: Nothing changed, because you have already eliminated once using getline.

Comment: @embedded4ever oh, then `print substr($0,11,8)`? sorry for guessing, I can't check that out for myself right now

Comment: i see, but not worked again :)